# Polymorphic passing of 2D vector of pointers into a function

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, polymorphism

I have a 2D vector of Tile pointers.

```
std::vector<std::vector<Tile*>> tileMap;
```

Tile **is a** Sprite

```
class Tile : Sprite
```

I need to pass a reference or pointer to my 2D vector of Tiles into a function expecting Sprites.

```
void RenderTiles(const std::vector<std::vector<Sprite*>>& TileMap); // won't work
```

A compliant way is to use iterators, [as suggested in this link.](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/CTR56-CPP.+Do+not+use+pointer+arithmetic+on+polymorphic+objects) This won't work though, as my function logic is dependent on being able to index into various parts of the 2D vector.

This function will be called many times a second, so it would be too much of a performance hit to copy the whole 2D vector into a new one of type Sprite.

What are my options? Is there anything besides switching to a C-style array and losing dynamic sizing?

Comment: `template<typename T> void RenderTiles(const std::vector<std::vector<T*>>& TileMap);`

Comment: C-style array won't work for all the same reasons. Why did you make `RenderTiles` take `Sprite`s and not `Tile`s to begin with? Do you ever pass something other than `Tile`s to it?

Comment: RenderTiles is in a library, so it's unaware of my Tile object and only works on Sprites. A C-style array would work though, as per the first compliant solution in the link.

Comment: I'm not clear if you have the ability to change `RenderTiles`, you suggest that you have, but then you say it's in a library which suggests that you haven't.

Comment: Sorry. To be clear, it's in a library that I'm writing, but I'm maintaining a boundary between the rendering logic and the rest of the engine. RenderTiles doesn't need the extra data from the Tile class, but it's being called from the engine logic, which does need Tiles instead of Sprites.

Comment: That first compliant solution builds an array of `S*` pointers that actually point to `T`. Which is exactly what you say you want to avoid - this is equivalent to making a `std::vector<std::vector<Sprite*>>` that's a copy of `tileMap`.

Comment: Perhaps you want `tileMap` to hold `Sprite*` pointers to begin with, and downcast them to `Tile*` as necessary. You would then be able to pass it straight to `RenderTiles`